# How to save chat history with OpenAI API?

Tags: python, openai-api

This code analyzes textual ice cream reviews using OpenAI's GPT-3.5-turbo model and saves the analysis results in JSON format. Here are the steps it follows:

1. §analyze_text§ function:

   Accepts the text of reviews and the starting identifier (start_id) for numbering reviews.
   Builds and sends a request to the GPT-3.5-turbo model, containing instructions for analyzing reviews and generating a JSON array of objects. Each object reflects a separate review indicating the topics mentioned and their tone (positive, negative, neutral).
   Returns the result of the model as a string, assumed to be JSON formatted text.
2. `is_valid_json` function:

   Checks whether the parsing result is a valid JSON array of objects.
   Makes sure that each object contains at least one mentioned topic with the key `"mentioned": true`.
3. `process_reviews_and_save_to_json` function:

   Reads text reviews from a file at the specified path.
   Processes reviews in batches (by default, 10 reviews at a time), using the analyze_text function to generate an analysis of each batch.
   Checks and validates the JSON received from the model for compliance with the specified criteria.
   Saves all successfully parsed and validated results to the JSON output file specified in the function parameters.

The problem is that I send the same original prompt every time.
Is it possible to send it once, the chat will remember it, and then I can just send batches of 10 lines for analysis every time without sending instructions every time?

```
import openai
import json  

openai.api_key = ""

def analyze_text(text,start_id):
    prompt =(f"""
    Analyze the provided ice cream reviews and generate a JSON array of objects, where each object corresponds to a single review. 

    Here is the rule for the JSON structure: If a topic within a review is mentioned, include it with 'mentioned': true and provide the sentiment. If a topic within a review is not mentioned, that topic should not be included in the JSON object at all.

    Start with the following reviews and construct the JSON array accordingly. For each review, include the following topics only if they are mentioned:

    {{
      "id": {start_id},  // Use start_id for numeration.\n
      // Include this field only if the taste or composition is mentioned in the review\n
      "taste_and_composition": {{"mentioned": true, "sentiment": "<positive/negative/neutral>"}},  // Set 'mentioned' to true if the review mentions the taste or composition of the ice cream, including sweetness, creaminess, presence of mix-ins, flavor of coatings, and waffle taste\n
      // Include this field only if the quality and freshness are mentioned in the review\n
      "quality_and_freshness": {{"mentioned": true, "sentiment": "<positive/negative/neutral>"}},  // Set 'mentioned' to true if the review mentions the quality and freshness of the ice cream, including its texture and consistency\n
      // Include this field only if the packaging is mentioned in the review\n
      "packaging": {{"mentioned": true, "sentiment": "<positive/negative/neutral>"}},  // Set 'mentioned' to true if the review mentions the packaging of the ice cream, including the size of the portion and the packaging itself\n
      // Include this field only if the price and value are mentioned in the review\n
      "price_and_value": {{"mentioned": true, "sentiment": "<positive/negative/neutral>"}},  // Set 'mentioned' to true if the review mentions the price of the ice cream and its value for the money\n
      // Include this field only if the delivery is mentioned in the review\n
      "delivery": {{"mentioned": true, "sentiment": "<positive/negative/neutral>"}}  // Set 'mentioned' to true if the review comments on the delivery of the ice cream, including the condition of the ice cream upon delivery\n
    }}

    Remove any topic that is not actually mentioned from the final JSON object for that review. The final JSON should only contain topics with 'mentioned': true.\n
    And every review should have al least one topic 100% percent.
    Reviews:
    {text}
    """
    )
    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
        ],
        temperature=0.7,
        max_tokens=2300,
        top_p=1.0,
        frequency_penalty=0.0,
        presence_penalty=0.0
    )
    return completion.choices[0].message['content'].strip()

def is_valid_json(json_array):
    if not isinstance(json_array, list):
        print("Ошибка: ожидался список объектов JSON.")
        return False

    for obj in json_array:
        if not isinstance(obj, dict):
            print("Ошибка: каждый элемент в списке должен быть словарём.")
            return False

        # Извлекаем топики, которые являются словарями
        topics = [value for value in obj.values() if isinstance(value, dict)]

        # Проверяем, что каждый топик имеет mentioned: true
        if not all(topic.get("mentioned") for topic in topics):
            return False

        # Проверяем, что хотя бы один топик присутствует
        if not topics:
            return False

    return True

def process_reviews_and_save_to_json(file_path, output_json_path='analyzed_reviews.json', max_attempts=10):
    results = []
    current_id = 1
    total_lines_processed = 0
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        while True:
            lines = []
            try:
                for _ in range(10):  # Измените это значение в соответствии с вашими потребностями
                    line = next(f).strip()
                    if line:
                        lines.append(line)
            except StopIteration:
                break  # Достигнут конец файла
            
            if not lines:
                break  # Если не осталось строк для обработки, завершаем цикл

            attempts = 0
            while attempts < max_attempts:
                text_part = " ".join(lines)
                analyzed_text = analyze_text(text_part,current_id)
                
                # Проверка на пустой или некорректный вывод перед декодированием
                if analyzed_text.strip():  # Убедитесь, что строка не пустая
                    try:
                        analyzed_json = json.loads(analyzed_text)
                        if is_valid_json(analyzed_json):
                            results.extend(analyzed_json)
                            total_lines_processed += len(lines)
                            current_id += len(lines)
                            print(f"Обработано {total_lines_processed} строк.")
                            break
                        else:
                            print("Попытка не прошла валидацию, повторяем...")
                            attempts += 1
                    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                        print(f"Ошибка при декодировании JSON: {e}, повторяем...")
                        attempts += 1
                else:
                    print("Получен пустой ответ от модели, повторяем...")
                    attempts += 1

    with open(output_json_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(results, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
    
    print(f"Результаты обработки сохранены в файл: {output_json_path}")

text_file_path = ''
output_json_path = ''

# Вызов функции для обработки отзывов и сохранения в JSON
process_reviews_and_save_to_json(text_file_path, output_json_path=output_json_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the prompt only once and then you can send 10 lines for analaysis.

Put the original prompt outside the analyze text function.

```
original_prompt = """
    Analyze the provided ice cream reviews and generate a JSON array of objects, where each object corresponds to a single review. 

    Here is the rule for the JSON structure: If a topic within a review is mentioned, include it with 'mentioned': true and provide the sentiment. If a topic within a review is not mentioned, that topic should not be included in the JSON object at all.

    Start with the following reviews and construct the JSON array accordingly. For each review, include the following topics only if they are mentioned:

    {
      "id": {start_id},  // Use start_id for numeration.\n
      "taste_and_composition": {"mentioned": true, "sentiment": "<positive/negative/neutral>"},  // Set 'mentioned' to true if the review mentions the taste or composition of the ice cream, including sweetness, creaminess, presence of mix-ins, flavor of coatings, and waffle taste\n
      "quality_and_freshness": {"mentioned": true, "sentiment": "<positive/negative/neutral>"},  // Set 'mentioned' to true if the review mentions the quality and freshness of the ice cream, including its texture and consistency\n
      "packaging": {"mentioned": true, "sentiment": "<positive/negative/neutral>"},  // Set 'mentioned' to true if the review mentions the packaging of the ice cream, including the size of the portion and the packaging itself\n
      "price_and_value": {"mentioned": true, "sentiment": "<positive/negative/neutral>"},  // Set 'mentioned' to true if the review mentions the price of the ice cream and its value for the money\n
      "delivery": {"mentioned": true, "sentiment": "<positive/negative/neutral>"}  // Set 'mentioned' to true if the review comments on the delivery of the ice cream, including the condition of the ice cream upon delivery\n
    }

    Remove any topic that is not actually mentioned from the final JSON object for that review. The final JSON should only contain topics with 'mentioned': true.\n
    And every review should have al least one topic 100% percent.
"""
```

You may reuse the prompt for every batch of reviews by putting it outside of the `analyze_text` function and substituting {start_id} with the actual start_id value. After that, you attach the reviews to the prompt and submit it for analysis. With this, calls to analyze_text in the future will just submit the batch of reviews; you only send the prompt once.

```
def analyze_text(text, start_id):
    prompt = original_prompt.replace("{start_id}", str(start_id))  
    prompt += "\nReviews:\n" + "\n".join(text) 
    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
        ],
        temperature=0.7,
        max_tokens=2300,
        top_p=1.0,
        presence_penalty=0.0,
        frequency_penalty=0.0
    )
    return completion.choices[0].message['content'].strip()
```

Comment: Don't you think this is the same thing. Every time I send the same prompt which invloves original ?

Comment: So there isn't anyway to do this currently using only model invokation. However, you can checkout using an agent. See https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/how-it-works
 this will allow you to give the agent a prompt and not have to pass it all the time on every invokation cycle